# How to compare the boolean values in PrintWhenExpression

Tags: jasper-reports

I have defined a parameter in jrxml file which is of type boolean.The value to this parameter is coming from my java class(true/false).If the value is true then i dont want to display the field.I am writing the expression as below.

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{flag}==false]]></printWhenExpression>
```

what is the problem with this expression.Here i am displaying the field only when the flag value is false.Can any one tell me.

Comment: ***`<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{flag}]]></printWhenExpression>`*** in case `<parameter name="flag" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>`

Comment: I have the exact same scenario and neither one of the suggestions worked for me.  @user1430163 - Did you find a working solution?  Could you either accept the answer that worked for you or post the solution that you came up with?

Answer (score 3):

After trying the other 2 suggestions here, and probably about 30 other things (java expressions kill me), I finally got the following working.  In my example I do not want to print a specific text field if the PRINT_INSTRUCTIONS Boolean parameter is TRUE, only if it is FALSE.

In iReport it looks like this:

```
new Boolean($P{PRINT_INSTRUCTIONS}.booleanValue() == false)
```

In the XML it looks like this:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($P{PRINT_INSTRUCTIONS}.booleanValue() == false)]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{flag}==Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Here is Expression of mine which is working:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue() % 2 == 0 ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
```